# Pausing a function "onClick"

Tags: javascript, pause

I'm currently working on an image slideshow with 5 buttons (Start, stop, pause, backwards, forwards) My start button loads an autoRun function which starts to play through the images while the backwards/forwards buttons skip/go back an image. I'm wondering how to pause the autoRun function when the pause button is clicked? It doesn't need to resume when clicked again, just needs to pause on the current image it's on. The stop function (once I've finished it) will end the function and go back to the start. Cheers

The HTML:

```
  <button onClick="autoRun()">Start</button>
  <button onClick="changeImage(-1); return false;">Previous Image</button>
  <button onClick="pause();">pause</button>
  <button onClick="changeImage(1); return false;">Next Image</button>
  <button onClick="stop();">Stop</button>



  </td>
```

The JavaScript:

```
var images = ["HGal0.jpg", "HGal1.jpg", "HGal2.jpg", "HGal3.jpg", "HGal4.jpg", "HGal5.jpg", "HGal6.jpg", "HGal7.jpg", "HGal8.jpg", "HGal9.jpg", "HGal10.jpg", "HGal11.jpg", "HGal12.jpg", "HGal13.jpg", "HGal14.jpg", "HGal15.jpg"];

var imageNumber = 0;
var imageLength = images.length - 1;

function changeImage(x) {
imageNumber += x;
// if array has reached end, starts over
if (imageNumber > imageLength) {
    imageNumber = 0;
}
if (imageNumber < 0) {
    imageNumber = imageLength;
}

document.getElementById("slideshow").src = images[imageNumber];

return false;
}

function autoRun() {
setInterval("changeImage(1)", 2000);

}
```

Comment: Have you read any [doco for `setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval)?

Comment: And [`clearInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval) << key

Comment: the function called Start() should be called autoRun(), no?

Comment: Yeah @jordaniac89 I just fixed that as I posted it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Set your interval in a variable:

```
var interval = setInterval("changeImage(1)", 2000);
```

And clear it with clearInterval():

```
function pause(){
  clearInterval(interval);
}
```

Comment: This seems to be on the right track, i'm still new to js especially intervals. The pause function is now working, but as soon as I hit the 'Start' button afterwards, it goes on with its loop (which it's supposed to) but the pause button will no longer work, so it seems to only work once. It's also running the autoRun on load now, instead of waiting til I press start.